# Rudin Theorem 8.22: Why $ \lim_{x \to \infty } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi_x(s)ds=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-s^2}ds $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

**Theorem 8.22** Stirling's formula：$$ \lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{(x/e)^x \sqrt{2\pi x}}=1\tag{103} $$

Some relevant formulas:
$$\Gamma(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt    \quad (0<x<\infty) \tag{93}$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-s^2}ds=\sqrt{\pi} \tag{101}$$

The following is Rudin's proof:[image]

The convergence theorem stated in Exercise 12 of Chap. 7 :

[image]

My questions:

(1) Why the convergence in (a) is uniform on $[-A, A]$ ?

(2) Why $ \lim_{x \to \infty } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi_x(s)ds=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-s^2}ds $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(2)$ follows immediately so long as you accept $(a)$-$(e)$, because $\psi_x(s)\to e^{-s^2}$.

It remains to justify uniform convergence on compact sets. Fix $A>0$. Observe that for all suitable $s,x$: $$|e^{-s^2}-e^{-s^2h(s\sqrt{2/x})}|=e^{-s^2}\cdot |1-e^{s^2(1-h(s\sqrt{2/x}))}|\le|1-e^{A^2(1-h(s\sqrt{2/x}))}|$$The exponential function is continuous at zero. Therefore, to demonstrate uniform convergence on $[-A,A]$ we need only demonstrate that $h(s\sqrt{2/x})$ converges uniformly to $1$.

The monotonicity of $h$ makes life easier for us; we may bound: $$h(A\sqrt{2/x})\le h(s\sqrt{2/x})\le h(-A\sqrt{2/x})$$Where $x$ is large. Individually, by continuity of $h$, it is true that: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}h(A\sqrt{2/x})=1,\,\lim_{x\to\infty}h(-A\sqrt{2/x})=1$$Coupling these *finitely* many individual limits with the squeeze theorem, it is apparent that $h(s\sqrt{2/x})\to 1$ uniformly in $s\in[-A,A]$. We are done.